# Replace all the occurrence even with regex php

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace all the occurrence of the string World [*] : with 2000.
Output: **20002000hello**


How can I achieve that?
I am currently using the below code but it is not working.

```
preg_replace("/World [(.*?)] : /", "2000", "World [23] : World[125] : hello",-1)
```

Comment: whats the input ?

Comment: World [23] : World [125] : hello

Comment: try this "/(World \[.*\] : )/"

Comment: or this "/(World \[.*?\] : )/"

Comment: It's not working

Comment: yes because the antislash doesnt work in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$out = preg_replace('/World\s*\[.*?\] : /', "2000", "World [23] : World[125] : hello");
//=> 20002000hello
```

`[` and `]` are special regex meta characters that need to escaped and make space after `World` optional with 0 or more matches.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I won't do that mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

I have this

```
/(World \[.*?\] : )/
```

https://regex101.com/r/vbqD7a/1

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "World [23] : World [125] : hello";
$str = preg_replace("/World (.*?) /", "2000", $str);
print $str;
```